Show install directory in Inno Setup, but do not allow change?
In in Inno Setup installer, I want to require the installation to be in a specific folder, but I want the user to see what the folder is. Is there a way to do this?
If I use DisableDirPage=no then the user can change the installation folder. If I use DisableDirPage=yes then the user cannot see where the installation will go.
Is it possible to show the folder without allowing it to be changed?
I am NOT asking how to force installation into a specific folder, as I already know that. I am ONLY asking how to show the installation folder to the user.

If you combine DisableDirPage=yes with AlwaysShowDirOnReadyPage=yes, then the directory will show on the "Ready to install" page.
[Setup]
DisableDirPage=yes
AlwaysShowDirOnReadyPage=yes


That is the answer - thank you. It should have been obvious to me, but wasn't.
